# > Let $V$ be finite-dimensional vector space, and $A,B \in L(V)$ nilpotent. If $A+B$ is nilpotent does $AB = BA$

Tags: vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be finite-dimensional vector space, and $A,B \in L(V)$ nilpotent. If $A+B$ is nilpotent does $AB = BA$?

I think not, but I couldn't think of any counterexample (I tried with matrix in $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ because multiplying in $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ isn't commutative but these were not good counterexamples ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $dim(V)\geq3$ then the space of upper triangular matrices with zero on the diagonal is not commutative, find two of its elements which do not commute.